# Text Messages From Python Script to T-Mobile No Longer Getting Through

Tags: python

For many months I have been using a script written in Python to send:

(1) Text messages to a T-Mobile phone,

(2) Text messages to an AT&T phone,

As  of 7 days ago (7/8/2023) the T-Mobile phone no longer gets any texts but the AT&T phone still gets all the texts.

I have experimented with sending text messages to the  T-Mobile phone from email accounts and those are received by the phone successfully.   I do this by emailing a message to ##########@tmomail.net.

I have included a simplified version of the script below. Note both the responses are {} which I believe means "no problems to report"

```
import smtplib

# Supply your own gmail SomeName, and T-Mobile and/or ATT numbers

server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )

server.starttls()

server.login( 'SomeName@gmail.com', 'app password from gmail' ) 

TMobileResponse=server.sendmail( 'SomeName@gmail.com', '1234567890@tmomail.net','First is Subject', 'Second is the message' ) 
print('TMobileResponse = ',TMobileResponse)

ATTResponse=server.sendmail( 'SomeName@gmail.com', '0987654321@txt.att.net','First is Subject', 'Second is the message' ) 
print('ATTResponse = ',ATTResponse)

server.quit()`
```

Comment: It's possible they are now identifying your messages as spam.  T-Mobile has pretty aggressive spam filtering.

Comment: How can I find out?  If it was spam I would hope I wouldn't get the {} response

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to know.  Are your messages "spam-like"?  And, no, email systems never notify the sender.  They just suck it up and throw it away.  Spam detection usually happens long after the ingest phase.

Comment: The "Subject" is 'First is Subject' and the "Message" is "'Second is the message'.  I have tried a few different Subjects and Messages.  Like a single letter "x".  All pass ATT but not T-Mobile

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of experimenting and trashing around I have come to the conclusion that T-Mobile is calling my messages Spam and discarding them.  I changed to using a different gmail account and they are coming through.
But I have been using the original account for months and months.  Then a few days ago T-M decided they are spam. I have tried to find a way to get T-M to accept them but no luck

The messages are all identical except for the date and time.

Funny, as I started this post I got 5 "Delivery Status Notification (Delay)" messages.  They are about one of my messages from 2 days ago sent by the same account that seems to be considered spam.

So, I can get by using the new gmail account but how long until T-M decides the new account is sending spam?

Comment: "how long until T-M decides the new account is sending spam?" Who knows. You'd be better off with an actual SMS-sending service (that you'll then need to pay for).

Comment: "The messages are all identical except for the date and time." I think you've identified the problem. If you are sending identical messages more often than once in a blue moon it is likely to increase the probability of them being flagged as spam.